# How to change Bokeh figure segment line width dynamically

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a figure containing a segment :

```py
p = figure(height=500, tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset", x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_location="right")

high_low_segment = p.segment(x0='time', y0='low', x1='time', y1='high', line_width=1, color='black', source=source)
```

(this is from the [OHLC example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/branch-2.4/examples/app/ohlc))

I'm wondering how to change the line_width of the segment dynamically - namely when the x-scale changes (catching `RangesUpdate` event) - to scale accordingly to the zoom level.

I'm new to bokeh so I'm not sure if it's possible directly in Python, if I have to wire some JS or if it's just impossible this way.
Maybe I should completely rewrite my figure or remove the segment and add a new one ?

Environment:

- bokeh 2.4.0
- python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, segment is the wrong choice to achieve scalable size rectangles.
Using [`Rect` glyph](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/rect.html) with `data` height and width units works out of the box.

```py
p.rect(x='time',
       y='high_low_y',
       fill_color='black',
       height='high_low_height',
       width=20000,
       line_width=0,
       angle=0,
       height_units='data',
       width_units='data',
       source=source
       )
p.rect(x='time',
       y='open_close_y',
       fill_color='open_close_color',
       height='open_close_height',
       width=60000,
       line_width=0,
       line_color='black',
       angle=0,
       height_units='data',
       width_units='data',
       source=source
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

with some widget via js_on_change or on_change.
for example : Slider

```
slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=1, title="line width")
spinner.js_link('value', high_low_segment.glyph, 'line_width')
```

or with on_change

```
def functionname(attr, old, new):
    high_low_segment.glyph.line_width = slider.value

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=1, title="line width")
spinner.on_change('value', functionname)
```

Comment: This is useful but doesn't fully answer the question: could you adapt your examples to be triggered by  a `RangesUpdate` event ?